# Is there a scalable formula to convert blocks of data into a vertical list?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have several blocks of data which look like this:

[image: Example block of data]

I need to take each row of data in each block and add it to a vertical list which contains all the data, a row being like the following:

[image: Example row]

I have about 10 blocks of data and I can't seem to think of a less painful way other than using a bunch of `INDEX` functions that I have to alter too often. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I would use VBA for this if you know any...  96-well plate?

Comment: I do not see the difference between the first picture and the second picture.  The rows appear to be the same.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I think the OP is just highlighting what a "row" is

Comment: That is correct. @TimWilliams Yup, 96 well plates all day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can reshape an array into a column with:

```
= LET( Matrix, B2:M10,
      rM, ROWS( Matrix ),
      cM, COLUMNS( Matrix ),
      idx, SEQUENCE( rM * cM, 1 , 0 ),
      INDEX( Matrix, INT( idx / cM ) + 1, MOD( idx, cM ) + 1 )
      )
```

Of course, B2:M10 can be any arbitrarily shaped array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic example of how to convert a rectangular range to an array.  If you need to deal with this type of data then VBA is a very useful skill to have.  This is where I started with VBA (many years ago...).

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, arr
    Set rng = Range("A1:L8")
    
    ArrayToCell BlockToList(rng), Range("N1") 'read by column
    
    ArrayToCell BlockToList(rng, False), Range("P1") 'read by column
    
End Sub

'convert a rectangular range into a 2-d single-column array
'  Read by row(default) or by column (pass False as second argument)
Function BlockToList(rng As Range, Optional rowMajor As Boolean = True)
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, dr, dc, arrData, arrOut, i As Long
    arrData = rng.Value
    dr = UBound(arrData, 1)
    dc = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To (dr * dc), 1 To 1)
    If rowMajor Then
        For m = 1 To dr
            For n = 1 To dc
                i = i + 1
                arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(m, n)
            Next n
        Next m
    Else
        For m = 1 To dc
            For n = 1 To dr
                i = i + 1
                arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(n, m)
            Next n
        Next m
    End If
    BlockToList = arrOut
End Function

'Utility method for populating an array to a range
Sub ArrayToCell(arr, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Its extra useful because it also makes a list from the columns in the block too (another question I had found a hack solution for). I know a little bit of VBA, and then moved to Python which I am more comfortable with now. However this project requires me to work with Excel, so you know when in Rome. Thanks again!