# How do I break a range into n chunks and run a function on each chuck and append the results into a single column?

Tags: excel, vba

[For context of the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808678/is-there-a-scalable-formula-to-convert-blocks-of-data-into-a-vertical-list). I have combined several of these 96 cell ranges into one larger range composed on `n` smaller ranges. Reason for doing this is to make it (more) scalable.

I have a range of data I want to break them up into `n` ranges/chunks and run my function on each (function below, shout out to @Tim Williams for the function) and combine the outputs all into a column. One solution I don't really like but I could do is to simply run the function on each `n` chunks/ranges and manually combine them, however, that's not really optimal for what I need. I am still pretty new to VBA, any ideas would be much appreciated!

The function I am using is as follows. Note my comment within the function:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, arr
    Dim Poolws As Worksheet
    Dim Combows As Worksheet
    Dim plates As Range
        
    Set Poolws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pools")
    Set Combows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Plates")
             
    Set rng = Combows.Range("C3:N66")
    Set plates = Combows.Range("A2")
    
    ArrayToCell BlockToList(rng, plates), Poolws.Range("A2") 'read by column
    
    ArrayToCell BlockToList(rng, plates, False), Poolws.Range("F2") 'read by column
    
End Sub

'convert a rectangular range into a 2-d single-column array
'  Read by row(default) or by column (pass False as second argument)
Function BlockToList(rng As Range, plates As Range, Optional rowMajor As Boolean = True)
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, dr, dc, arrData, arrOut, platenum, i As Long
    arrData = rng.Value
    platenum = plates.Value
    dr = UBound(arrData, 1)
    dc = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To (dr * dc), 1 To 1)
    If rowMajor Then
        For m = 1 To dr
            For n = 1 To dc
                i = i + 1
                arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(m, n)
            Next n
        Next m
    Else
        For m = 1 To dc
        ' I think something in the following lines needs to change.
        ' divide array by plantenum into that many arrays then on each
        ' run the following, pasting the results sequentially in a column
            For n = 1 To dr / platenum
                i = i + 1
                arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(n, m)
            Next n
        Next m
    End If
    BlockToList = arrOut
End Function

'Utility method for populating an array to a range
Sub ArrayToCell(arr, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach that:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Const PLT_ROWS As Long = 8
    Const PLT_COLS As Long = 12

    Dim rng As Range, arr, rngOut As Range
    Dim Poolws As Worksheet
    Dim Combows As Worksheet
    Dim plates As Range
        
    Set Poolws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pools")
    Set Combows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Plates")
             
    Set rng = Combows.Range("C3").Resize(PLT_ROWS, PLT_COLS)
    Set rngOut = Poolws.Range("F2")
    
    Do While Application.CountA(rng) > 0
        ArrayToCell BlockToList(rng, False), rngOut     'by column or by row?
        Set rng = rng.Offset(rng.Rows.Count, 0)         'next input block
        Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(0, 1)                'output next column over?
        'Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(rng.Cells.Count, 0) '...or append to previous?
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Rest of code from previous question is unchanged - in order to keep your code as modular as possible it's best to avoid special-casing your "core" methods where you can.

If you're dealing with multi-plate output files from an instrument, ideally you want to be reading directly from those files (typically after opening them in Excel so you don't need to do the parsing) with no intermediate copy/paste/consolidate steps.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (for anyone who cares):

I added a loop that breaks the range/array/chunk into sections (in this case I know they are always 8 "tall"). I'm sure someone could have a better solution, but this one worked for me! Code as follows:

```
'convert a rectangular range into a 2-d single-column array
'  Read by row(default) or by column (pass False as second argument)
Function BlockToList(rng As Range, plates As Range, Optional rowMajor As Boolean = True)
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, dr, dc, arrData, arrOut, platenum, i As Long
    arrData = rng.Value
    platenum = plates.Value
    dr = UBound(arrData, 1)
    dc = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To (dr * dc), 1 To 1)
    If rowMajor Then
        For m = 1 To dr
            For n = 1 To dc
                i = i + 1
                arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(m, n)
            Next n
        Next m
    Else
        For o = 0 To platenum * 8
            If ((o * 8) + 8) <= dr Then
                For m = 1 To dc
                ' divide array by plantenum into that many arrays then on each
                ' run the following, pasting the results sequentially in a column
                    For n = ((o * 8) + 1) To ((o * 8) + 8)
                        i = i + 1
                        arrOut(i, 1) = arrData(n, m)
                    Next n
                Next m
            End If
        Next o
    End If
    BlockToList = arrOut
End Function
```